# KeyError in dict but Key exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, keyerror

I am working on parsing a dict of dicts which look likes this:

```
data = {0: {},
        1: {'1': 'M_AVL_002'},
        2: {'2': 'CloudServiceAvailability'},
        3: {'3': 'P_001'},
        4: {'4': '2.592 x10^6'},
        5: {'4': 'second'},
        6: {'3': 'E_001'},
        7: {'4': ' 100 x (P_001- M_TQD_001)/P_001'},
        8: {'4': 'ISO80000'},
        9: {'4': 'percentage'},
        10: {'1': 'M_TQD_001'},
        11: {'2': 'TotalQualifiedDowntime'},
        12: {'3': 'E_001'},
        13: {'4': '?(M_QDT_001)'},
        14: {'4': 'ISO80000'},
        15: {'4': 'second'}}
```

I want to access some values like this:

```
for metric in XML.findall("{http://standards.iso.org/iso-iec/19086/-2/ed-1/en}Metric"):
        for row,value in data.items() :
            if (row==0):
                pass
            else :
                for col,v in value.items():
                    if (col=="1"):
                        metric.set('id',str(data[row][col]))
                    if (col=="2"):
                        metric.set('description',str(data[row][col]))
                    if (col=="3"):
                        if (str(data[row][col]).startswith("E")):
                            metric.find('{http://standards.iso.org/iso-iec/19086/-2/ed-1/en}Expression').set("id",str(data[row][col]))
                            metric.find('{http://standards.iso.org/iso-iec/19086/-2/ed-1/en}Expression').set("expressionStatement",str(data[str(int(row)+1)][str(int(col)+1)]))
                            metric.find('{http://standards.iso.org/iso-iec/19086/-2/ed-1/en}Expression').set("expressionLanguage",str(data[str(int(row)+2)][str(int(col)+1)]))
                            metric.find('{http://standards.iso.org/iso-iec/19086/-2/ed-1/en}Expression').set("unit",str(data[str(int(row)+3)][str(int(col)+1)]))
                        elif (str(data[row][col]).startswith("P")):
                            for param in metric.findall('{http://standards.iso.org/iso-iec/19086/-2/ed-1/en}Parameter'):
                                if(str(data[row][col])==param.get('id')):
                                    a=str(data[row][col])
                                    print(str(int(row)+1),str(int(col)+1))
                                    b=str(data[str(int(row)+1)][str(int(col)+1)])
                                    c=str(data[str(int(row)+2)][str(int(col)+1)])
                                    param.set("id",a)
                                    param.set("parameterStatement",b)
                                    param.set("unit",c)
                                else:
                                    pass
                        elif (str(data[row][col]).startswith("R")):
                            for rule in metric.findall('{http://standards.iso.org/iso-iec/19086/-2/ed-1/en}Rule'):
                                if(str(data[row][col])==rule.get('id')):
                                    a=str(data[row][col])
                                    b=str(data[str(int(row)+1)][str(int(col)+1)])
                                    rule.set("id",a)
                                    rule.set("ruleStatement",b)
                                else :
                                    pass
```

However, I have a `KeyError` on the line where `b` is assigned. I have tried to print `row` and `col` and checked if row+1 and col+1 are keys, and they are.

In the case where the program crashes row=6 and col=3 so there is a value at this emplacement but it is also true for row=7 and col=4, and I have : `KeyError :'7'`

Comment: When assigning `b`, you're using `[str(col+1)]`.  I think this should probably be `[str(int(col) + 1)]` because your second key is a string and addition must be performed on numbers.

Comment: @Rachel I've also tried it didn't work too

Comment: Your problem is that strings and numbers are different types in Python, and the number `2` is not equal to the string `'2'`.

Comment: Can you put what your expected output is for `a` and `b`?

Comment: @JackMoody `a='E_001'` and b should be equal to `' 100 x (P_001- M_TQD_001)/P_001'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for row,value in data.items() :
    for col,v in value.items():
        a=data[row][col]
        b=data[row+1][str(int(col)+1)]
```

But at point row=4 and col=4, you will get error, cause there is no data[5]['5'] element in data.

Please, notice that data['4'] and data[4] are different things. That's why you need to get dict element by correct key.

Comment: so why i do i get `KeyError: '4'` when i am at point row=3 col =3 and try to access data [4][4] through `b=str(data[str(int(row)+1)][str(int(col)+1)])`

Comment: Because you are trying access '4', when it's 4

Comment: all dict keys are string aren't they ?

Comment: No, they can be of any immutable type. so data['4'] and data[4] are different things

Comment: You have int keys at first, but then str keys. so you need `data[row+1][str(int(col)+1)]`

Comment: OOOH thank you very much you should update your answer i will accept it !

Answer (score 0):

The outer dictionary's keys are integers, so you shouldn't convert them to strings.

```
for row,value in data.items() :
    for col,v in value.items():
        a=data[row][col]
        b=data[row+1][str(int(col)+1)]
```

However, you will have `KeyError` again! Print the keys you are trying to access.

```
for row,value in data.items() :
    for col,v in value.items():
        a=data[row][col]
        print(row+1, str(int(col)+1))
```

You will get:

```
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 5
7 4
8 5
9 5
10 5
11 2
12 3
13 4
14 5
15 5
16 5
```

Not all of them are valid. So, 'KeyError in dict but Key exists' is not a true statement!

Comment: This is correct.  The dataset is invalid for this particular algorithm.

Comment: Sure i know that when i try to access but i never tries to access keys that are not available...

Comment: i made a generalization @Rachel for algorithm but i am never in a case where i am trying to access something which doesn't exists

Comment: i have done that and that's why i am asking on stackoverflow because i can't figure it out